# AG-Grid - Show sort icon without reloading data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an angular application and when I load my page the columns are not yet defined.
The columns are defined when I retrieve the data (which are already sorted).

So if I apply a state on my sorted column (after the data are initialized), the data are refreshed again and I want to avoid this.

Is there a solution to show the sort icon without AG-Grid refresh the data ?

To be more explicit, here is my angular code :

```
getRows(params: any): void {
  //retrieve my data
  this.myservice.getAll(params.currentPage, params.pageSize, params.sort).subscribe((data) => {
    //send my datas to AG-Grid
    params.successCallBack(data.results, data.totalItems);
    if (params.currentPage == 0 && this.firstLoad) {
      //my datas contain the columns definition
      this.initGrid(data.viewParams);
    }
  });
}

initGrid(viewParams: ViewParamsModel): void {
    this.firstLoad = false;
    this.dataGrid.setColumnDefs(viewParams.columns);

    //I try with this but it reloads my data
    this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
         state: [
         {
            colId: 'name',
            sort: 'asc',
         }],
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried and what is the issue posting some code. Does every column data is sorted and you want to show sort icon enabled by default for all sorted columns.

Comment: @Mahi I updated my post.
I want to display the sort icon for one column but when i set the column I don't want the data to be reload

Answer (score 1):

When doing `this.dataGrid.setColumnDefs(viewParams.columns)`

add   `sort: 'desc'/'asc'`

```
columnDefs: [
    {
      field: 'Column1',
      sort: 'desc',   // <====== add this
    },
```

Comment: Does this helped.

Comment: If I did that, the getRows function is recall. And I want to avoid that